# Divide N Hot dogs among M persons

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

There are N hot dogs and M people and we need  to divide the hot dogs equally. Now we need  to calculate the minimum number of cuts required to distribute the hot dogs equally.

In order to divide the hot dogs, the number of cuts splitting individual hot dogs must be as small as possible.

**How to calculate minimum Cuts for N hot dogs to be equally distributed among M persons?**

**Example 1:** Let N =2 and M=6 then answer is 4

**Explanation** : If there are two hot dogs and six tasters, it is
sufficient to split each hot dogs into three equal parts, making a total of four cuts.

**Example 2 :** Let N=3 and M=4 then answer is 3

**Explanation :**  If there are three hot dogs and four tasters , one possibility is cutting off three quarters of each hot dogs. Those larger parts will each go to one of the tasters, while the fourth taster
will get the three smaller pieces (quarters) left over.

Comment: Ad ex. 2: note that you can pile up the hot dogs and get 6 parts in 2 cuts.

Comment: @ciuak But we need just 4 pieces.

Comment: Ugh. I meant "ad ex. 1"

Comment: @ciuak Oh..But for each hot dog their are 2 cuts so for 2 hotdogs total cuts are still 4

Comment: I meant that you can, for example, put them all next to each other like this: http://pastebin.com/5UFLA3Rm

Comment: @ciuak But still on stacking of hot dogs one above other the cuts for each hot dog is still 2.So 2+2=4

Comment: Hmm, now you need to choose if you're interested in CUTS or MOVES.

Comment: @ciuak Obviosuly we need to count CUTS

Comment: Can you please make this into a question? E.g. "How do I calculate $\textrm{numberOfCuts}(N,M)$?" I don't see a single question mark above.

Comment: @amcalde Done..I edited the post

Comment: OK so if $N \le M$ then every body gets $\floor(N/M)$ whole hot dogs plus hot dog parts totalling $(N \mod M)/M$. The hard part of the question then is only dealing with $N < M$.

Comment: This problem [is from the contest "Insomnia 2014"](http://www.codechef.com/INSM2014/problems/INSM03), which [was ongoing](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=CodeChef+%3A+Insomnia+2014&iso=20140926T22&p1=44&ah=6) when the question was posted.

Answer (score -1):

OK I think I've got it.

Recursion:

```
f(N,M) = 
{
  if( M divides N ) return 0
  else if(N >= M) return( f( N - M*floor(N/M), M ) )
  else return( N*floor( M/N ) + f( N, M - N*floor( M/N ) )
}
```

So if you have a multiple of $M$ hot dogs, no cuts need be made. If you have enough for everyone to get at least one with some left over (second case), then you're really just concerned with computing the remainder.

Finally if you have not enough for everyone to get one, do a greedy algorithm. Make $\textrm{ceil}(M/N)$ cuts on each hot dog, giving $N*\textrm{ceil}(M/N)$ people their fair share. Leaving $ M -N*\textrm{ceil}(M/N)$ people to split the remnants, which are now $N$ (smaller) hot dogs.

Not sure if this is THE BEST way, but it is certainly easily computable. There may or may not be some nice combinatorial formula.
Cheers.

Comment: Can you please explain with example

Comment: Sure: Take 11 hot dogs and 8 people.  First: everyone gets 1. (Case two in my algorithm) No cuts for that, so then you take the 3 remaining hot dogs (11 - 8*floor(11/8) == 3) and you need to divide these now among 8 people hungry for seconds.

Comment: What would be output for this case according to you?

Comment: So now you have 3 Hot dogs and 8 people. So everyone should get 3/8 of a hot dog. Take each whole hot dog and cut out two sections of 3/8. That's two cuts on three hot dogs. 6 cuts. And you've satisfied 6 hungry people who now have had their fair share and are done. You're left with three pieces of 1/4 of a hot dog and 2 people still waiting on that 3/8 extra bit. so you're computing $f(3,2)$ on the remainder (we only count cuts so it doesn't matter that from this point the dogs are smaller.)

Comment: So now you have $N>M$ again and you give each of the two people one bit (1/4) of  a dog. No cuts.

Then the last piece is split between them, $f(1,2)$. One piece with two people, one more cut.

Comment: So you've done: $f(11,8) = f(11-8*\textrm{floor}(11/8),8) = f(3,8)$

Comment: Sorry, continuing:$f(11,8) = f(3,8) = 3*\textrm{floor}(8/3) + f(3,8 - 3*\textrm{floor}(8/3)) = 6 + f(3,2) = 6 + f(1,2) = 6 + 1 = 7$

Comment: Each time through you either have an excess of people or of hot dogs. Too many hot dogs? Just hand 'em out (you decrease the number of hot dogs for the next iteration). Too many people? cut of pieces and hand those out (you decrease the number of people for the next iteration). Eventually, you're done.

Comment: How f(1,2) is 1 ?According to your recursion it must be 0

Comment: Also explain your recursion for first example .It will return 0 here.if am not wrong

Comment: No it's 1. Two doesn't divide One. If you have five people and ten dogs, then it's zero cuts. Five divides ten. $f(1,2)$ means 1 dog, 2 people. Cut it in half or $f(1,2) = 1*\textrm{floor}(2/1) +f(0,0)$ Which is fine because zero divides zero so $f(0,0) =0 $.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your last comment. The first time through $f(11,8)$ just returns $f(3,8)$. There were no cuts made and it's just instructing you to calculate something else.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to say.: http://pastebin.com/Z5FMhzep

Comment: If am wrong then please correct me

Comment: In your code you want $N \% M == 0$ That happens when $M$ divides $N$ So if $N=10,$ $M=5$ ( five people ten dogs) then $N \% M$ is zero because $M$ divides $N$. I think your code has it written backwards. If you have further questions we should move this to chat.

Comment: So was this not required ?then what you mean by your first if statement that if( M divides N ) return 0 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17465/discussion-between-amcalde-and-user119249).